# How to enable CORS allow-origin header in express server with swagger-ui

Tags: express, cors, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, access-control

My API server doesn't change or overwrite the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

I have an Angular 2+ application with an Express/Swagger-UI API.

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the API cannot be '*' because I use 'withCredentials' in my requests and it's trigger an error on the browser.

I've used 'cors' for setting the CORS headers. Like this:

```
'use strict';

var configuration = require('./configuration');
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var compression = require('compression');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(compression());

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  swaggerExpress.register(app);
  var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
  mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
  mongoose.connect(appConfig.dbConection());
  mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
  mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
    app.listen(port);
  })
});
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const YAML = require('yamljs');
const swaggerDocument = YAML.load('./api/swagger/swagger.yaml');

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:4200', 'http://127.0.0.1:10010'];
app.use(cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
            return callback(new Error('The CORS policy for this site does not allow the specified Origin'), false);
        }
        return callback(null, true);
    },
    exposedHeaders: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization', 'api_key', 'x-api-key'],
    credentials: true
}));
```

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin should match the array of allowed hosts.

When I call the API from the browser, it first make an OPTIONS request, that look correct, like this:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:10010/v1/loginApp
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:10010
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-api-key
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,api_key,x-api-key
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 08:25:53 GMT
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By: Express
```

But then it makes the GET/POST request, and then it has the default headers again:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:10010/v1/loginApp
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:10010
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,api_key,x-api-key
Content-Length: 770
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 08:25:53 GMT
ETag: W/"302-BwX5DjK/lUY+ueP6UZ9TgWOTw/s"
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express
```

I think something (probably swagger-UI) is overwriting my headers configuration, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your CORS middleware **before** the Swagger GET/POST handlers.

The OPTIONS request is succeeding because Swagger doesn't register an OPTIONS handler, so the request reaches the middleware.

The GET/POST requests are failing before the Swagger handlers accept the request before it reaches the CORS middleware.

Move `app.use(cors({...` so it is **before** `app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi...`.

Comment: Hello Quentin, thanks for your answer. I've tried moving the cors setting to the beginning and I've the same output in my request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if swagger-express-mw comes with CORS support built-in, see `swagger_controllers` in your `config/default.yaml`. I had the same issue and fixed it by removing `cors` from there.

Like you, I suspect it's overwriting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header but didn't have time to check it properly.